# Multiplying by i** is it possible in C? Like i++ why i**doesn't work in C?

Tags: c, multiplication

Is it possible to multiply using `i**` in C?
For example, I can increment `i` using `i++`. Why doesn't `i**` work in C?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int result;
    for (int i = 2; i < 100; i**){
        result = i + 1;
        printf("%i\n", result);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Simply because there's no `**` operator in C language.

Comment: i++ means add 1. i** should mean what? Multiply by 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. There is no operator like `**` in C unlike unary increment (`++`) and decrement (`--`) operators. You should have try `i *= i`.

Answer (score 3):

"i++" is shorthand for "i = i + 1".
If there were an "i**" it would, by extension, mean "i = i * 1" and be incredibly useless. So they never implemented it.

Even after editing to clarify grammar, it still isn't clear from your question that you expect "i**" to perform as "i = i * i". I'm guessing that is what you meant from the answer you accepted. If you learn to explain things clearly to others you will find that you think more clearly and can work out the answer to many questions for yourself.

Comment: Disagree! If (i >= 2) then then it ( i**) makes sense. But it wasn't implemented because we often start count from 0 or 1. But in such a case (i = 2 or greater)  we can use i *= i.  PS: I'm just starting learning programming.

Comment: Read what I said closely: i++ is equivalent to "i = i +1" so therefore "i**" would be equivalent to "i=i*1". If in this case i=2 then "i**" would equate to "i=2*1" and we would end up with i remaining as 2. Thus "i**" becomes a useless operation. You seem to intend that "i**" would expand to "i = i * i" and yes, this operation would be useful. However you never actually stated this anywhere. If you had then you might have looked at it and realised that there was an inconsistency between "i++" and your proposed behaviour for "i**". inconsistent behaviour invariably leads to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Possible, but instead of `i**` which doesn't work, you need to use:

```
for (int i = 2; i < 100; i *= i)
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, **multiplication** operation does not use in `for` loop **increment/decrement** part because suppose our `variable(i)` start from `0`, then every time multiplication become `0`.

Comment: That makes no sense... If you did multiplication in a loop, of course you would make sure to start with **anything other** than `0`.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiplying by `i**` is it possible in C? Like `i++` why `i**`doesn't work in C?**
No,it's not possible. for your second quesition answer is explained like, 
Basically , increment and decrement have exceptional usage as pre increment and post increment and a language cannot be extended just if someone needs an additional functionality as it would slow down because of extending its grammer.

So most used `++i,i++,--i,i--` are present and not others

You can use some codes like this for your task:

```
 i*=i;
 =i*i;
```